# Controlling whether p2 updates a dependency when an acceptable version is already installed

Tags: eclipse, p2

Suppose I'm installing or updating Eclipse feature A and feature A has a dependency on feature B of version 10 or greater.  My eclipse installation already has version 10 of feature B installed and there is a version 15 of feature B available from the same update site. The default behaviour of p2 seems to be to always update feature B to the latest available version even if the currently installed version would do.

Always updating to the latest version of feature B is probably desirable most of the time, but  in my case feature B is pretty big and I would like to skip the update unless the new version is absolutely required.

I can't seem to find a way to skip the update of feature B and was looking for suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can un-check the "Contact all update sites during installation.." in the Install New Software window. This way you will install only your feature(A) after the dependency is verified (B v 10).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the version of feature B, explicitly install that feature. Then, when checking for updates, p2 will explicitly show you what version it can update feature B to. If you don't like the update, simply de-select it and have p2 only update feature A.